# Load data on Bower plugin for a progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, radio-button, bower

I recently came across bower a web-tool to develop a progress bar. I have implemented a progress bar as series of radio buttons aligned next to each other. The concept is to load data from a `.edf` file to the browser upon clicking the radio buttons. All these work fine before I apply the Bower scripts. When I make a transition from one radio button to another I would like to have an effect which shows a transition while clicking on each button. Can I get some advice here if I can achieve this by applying any of the bootstrap classes or to modify the code existing? The snippet I have added is not loading the Bower libraries, otherwise it would look similar to this.

[image]

```js
$('.radios').radiosToSlider({ animation: true, });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"/>=
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/radios-to-slider/dist/jquery.radios-to-slider.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/radios-to-slider/dist/radios-to-slider.css"/>
<div class="radios">
    <label for="option1" class="btn">
     <input id="option1" name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(0)" checked>
    </label>
    <label for="option2" class="btn">
     <input id="option2" name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(1)">
    </label>
    <label for="option3" class="btn">
     <input id="option3" name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(2)">
    </label>
    <label for="option4" class="btn">
     <input id="option4" name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(3)">
    </label>
    <label for="option5" class="btn">
     <input id="option5" name="options" type="radio" autocomplete="off" onchange="dataSegment(4)">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, I didn't downvote. Second of all, I don't have a solution. Other people downvoted because your code was formatted very strangely, making it difficult to read. You also need to provide the current result, and your desired result.

Comment: I already have the solution in my code. I don't have the privilege to add jsfiddle to it. Sorry, it showed that you had downvoted.

Comment: Try using the ["snippet" button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet#answer-356679).

Comment: @fin444 I have added snippet now. Could you please suggest any solution apart from downvoting for indentation? thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using a URL that is local to a website. Notice that you have no protocol in the URL (`https://`, `http://`, etc). I did a little digging, and the URL you should be using is http://rubentd.com/bower_components/radios-to-slider/dist/jquery.radios-to-slider.js

Comment: Thanks @fin444 for your suggestion. I am using that code in my local hence it is working fine. here for the snippet, we can definitely make use of the URL that you posted. But my concern is regarding data loading on to the website upon clicking the radio button. I cannot see the data transferred to the web page with Bower plugins on. Without the radios class defined under div tag data loads well. I want to load the data when I use bower as well.